# I am not able to append a for loop to a div tag in my HTML body. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

This is my code... not sure what is wrong.

I am trying to append a while loop to HTML in the div tag `#putTheTreeInHere`.

Please help.

```js
function loop () {
    var index = 1;
    var row = "<font color=green><b>^</b></font>";
    var newRow= row;

    while ( index <= 10 ) {
        document.write( "<center>"+newRow+"</center><br>" );
        newRow = newRow + row;
        index += 1;
    }
}


function displayTree () {
    $( "#putTheTreeInHere" ).append( loop() )
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    displayTree();
});
```

Comment: Um the loop function is not returning anything

Comment: Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ofg90z0r/

Comment: `document.write`? `font`? `color=green`? This is 2014! I'm not trying to be harsh here, but please don't use those things anymore, and try to find a descent tutorial!

Comment: `center` is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see  http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/3k0x3c4L/1/
I have change font tag with a span and i centered the text in the div with a css
    #putTheTreeInHere{ text-align: center;}

in loop function dont use document.write...

```
function loop () {
   var index = 1;
   var row = '<span style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">^</b></span>';
   var html = "";
   var newRow= row;

   while ( index <= 10 ) {
     html +=  newRow+"<br>" ;
     newRow = newRow + row;
     index += 1;
   }
   return html
}
```

Comment: Can I add another loop to this function once the first one is completed?

Comment: sure, function displayTree () {
    $( "#putTheTreeInHere" ).append( loop() + loop() )
}, but is more intersting if you parametrize the loop...
http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/3k0x3c4L/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a value in the function

```
function loop()
{
var index=1;
var row= "<font color=green><b>^</b></font>";
var newRow= row;

while(index<=10)
    {
    document.write("<center>"+newRow+"</center><br>");
    newRow= newRow+row;
index+=1;
    }

    // Return the value
    return nextRow;  // Or return whatever value you want
}
```

This makes it so the function actually emits data when used with-in programming.

---

(P.S. Since you're knew, I'll let you know something.  If this answered solved your problem, you click the green checkmark to accept it)